# what do they mean if of cpu intensive task in nodejs? in correlation to the database doing cpu intensive task

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

what do they mean if of cpu intensive task in nodejs? if my workload is mostly done in Database does nodejs waiting for database to complete does that count as cpu intensive task for nodejs?

my database is cpu intensive task.

Answer (score 2):

> what do they mean if of cpu intensive task in nodejs? i

Nodejs uses only one CPU to run your Javascript.  Other things that run in other processes (such as your database) have their own strategy for using CPUs and do not directly affect the CPU usage within node.js.

So, if your Javascript itself is doing CPU-intensive things (in your own Javascript) like some really hard calculations, then node.js will get bogged down and not be able to process incoming requests in a responsive way.  For a server, this is generally considered a bad situation because the server will be non-responsive during the long calculations.

Making asynchronous calls to something that runs in another process (like a database) does not use hardly any CPU in node.js.  The node.js process makes the asynchronous call which starts the external operation and then that asynchronous call (nearly immediately) returns control back to node.js and node.js returns back to the event loop and is immediately ready to process other incoming events.  Then, when the asynchronous operation completes, a new event will get inserted into the event loop which will trigger the asynchronous completion callback and your node.js app can then process the result.

> If my workload is mostly done in Database does nodejs waiting for database to complete does that count as cpu intensive task for nodejs?

No.  As long as the database is running in another process, that will not count as a CPU intensive task for node.js and will not block the event loop in node.js in the same way that a long running Javascript calculation would.

It will certainly use overall CPU cycles in the server, but we're assuming that there is both more than one CPU core available (so the database isn't hogging all possible CPU ) and that even if we're keeping all the CPUs busy, the OS will still time slice between the threads so node.js can still run fine.

P.S. Nodejs has always been able to use child processes and now has worker threads so you can do CPU intensive things in either one of those and also not block the main event loop.